# make form visible on keydown event then focus and clear input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a table where the cells accept keyboard events.  I also have a form that's hidden initially. I want a key event to display the form and focus on an input field, but when I do this, the key value that fired the event appears in the input field - how can I not have this character displayed? (for example, press 'x', and the form appears with 'x' in the text field - I'd like that field to be blank).

### CSS

```
table.thistbl td {
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
}

#formid {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 40px;
  left: 20px;
  top: 60px;
  background-color: #CCC;
}
```

### JavaScript / jQuery:

```
$(function() {

  $('#tablediv').on('keydown', 'td', function(e) {
      $('#formid').show();
      $('#inputid').focus();
  });

});
```

### HTML:

```
<div id="tablediv">
<table class="thistbl">
  <tr>
    <td tabindex="0"></td>
    <td tabindex="0"></td>
    <td tabindex="0"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>

<form id="formid">
  <input type="text" tabindex="1" id="inputid" />
</form>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rino_Raj/gn185Lc8/)

Comment: just a thought... : you could try the keyup-event instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `keyup` instead of `keydown`

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/kiirosora/506xt9mr/)

Comment: Arg - so simple!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about a short delay?

```
$('#tablediv').on('keydown', 'td', function(e) {
    setTimeout(funtion(){
        $('#formid').show();
        $('#inputid').focus();
    }, 20);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you insist to use `keydown`, add `e.preventDefault()` to prevent that event's default behavior. But I think KiiroSora09's answer that switch to `keyup` is better.

```js
$(function() {

  $('#tablediv').on('keydown', 'td', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('#formid').show();
      $('#inputid').focus();
  });

});
```

```css
table.thistbl td {
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
}

#formid {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 40px;
  left: 20px;
  top: 60px;
  background-color: #CCC;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tablediv">
<table class="thistbl">
  <tr>
    <td tabindex="0"></td>
    <td tabindex="0"></td>
    <td tabindex="0"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>

<form id="formid">
  <input type="text" tabindex="1" id="inputid" />
</form>
```

Comment: This also works, but in my application I have no issues using keyup, so I can stick with that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try including

```
$('#inputid').focus().attr('value', '');
```

What you are actually doing here is After focusing just emptying the `value`

Like below

```
$(function() {

  $('#tablediv').on('keydown', 'td', function(e) {
      $('#formid').show();
      $('#inputid').focus().attr('value', '');
  });

});
```